# deploying app to gae from eclipse throws error

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a GAE project via eclipse and when i do that it throws the error as 
Reading application configuration data...

```
Beginning interaction for module default...
0% Scanning for jsp files.
Success.
Temporary staging for module default directory left in /Users/vskumar/eclipse/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.deploy/tmp/1483647936598/staging
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Response error: Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com
```

How do i fix this

Comment: Can you try a different DNS server, e.g. 8.8.8.8?

Comment: The Google Cloud SDK includes a network diagnostics tool:
```sh
$ gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```